# Use of different prepositions before and after and

Tags: prepositions

Is the following sentence wrong?

> A disruption **in** one domain often cascades into parallel disruptions **to** other domains.

I think it is correct because **disruption in** and **disruption to** both are correct.

But in my book it is given that only **disruption in** should be used at both the places.

Comment: I'm confused. Your sentence doesn't have an "and" which you reference in your last question.

The prepositions seem fine to me. My problem is the fact that your example has the wrong grammatical number. My brain wants to read it as "disruptions to other domains".

Comment: The only thing syntactically wrong with the sentence is that the final word should be **domains** (plural). You can use either **in** or **to** in both places, or you can mix them in either order. However, depending on exactly what you're trying to say, there is a difference in meaning between *disruption to* and *disruption in*. This sentence alone doesn't convey enough information to tell if one or the other should have been used in either location.

Comment: @JasonBassford sorry I have put it right.